# Cassandra: Request did not complete within rpc_timeout

Tags: cassandra, exception, query-timeout

i was working with Cassandra 1.2.4 probably, after restoring some key-space when i tried to query in a key-space it gave me `Request did not complete within rpc_timeout`

so i checked `system.log & output.log` under `/var/log/cassandra` path

i just find this exception:

> Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:42,5,main] java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.CorruptSSTableException: java.io.EOFException

what is the reason ? and how can i get rid of rpc_timeout

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

From the EOFException I take it that your problem is not the rpc_timeout but a corrupt data file. And it seams that Cassandra is not properly handling the exception and never returns the error to the piece of server code that "holds" your client connection and waits for data to send back to the client. Thus the timeout.

You could try and run `nodetool repair <your_keyspace>`. Maybe it is able to fix the corrupted data file. If not, try to drop the keyspace and restore it again.

To answer your question. The timeouts are set in the cassandra.yaml file in the config directory of your cassandra installation on each node.

Comment: thanks @Ralf nodetool repair does not work and i try to restore again but does not work , all other table from that keyspace work fine but that table that had problem again give ma a `rpc_timeout`

Comment: I forgot to add that repair only makes sense if you have other cluster nodes where from the data can be pulled during the repair. Do you run multiple nodes? Apparently you also need to delete the corrupt SSTable. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898085/cassandra-eofexception-thrown-on-some-queries-after-a-power-failure).